# MySql Client pip package isn't installing / is broken

Tags: python, django, django-models, pip, mysql-python

When I run the command:
`pip3 install mysqlclient` or `pip install mysqlclient`

I get the following error:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
      /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-jpxeffqw/mysqlclient_fed1a50532b74bc1aeaab814d12b88df/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
          metadata, options = get_config()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-jpxeffqw/mysqlclient_fed1a50532b74bc1aeaab814d12b88df/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
          libs = mysql_config("libs")
        File "/tmp/pip-install-jpxeffqw/mysqlclient_fed1a50532b74bc1aeaab814d12b88df/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
          raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
      OSError: mysql_config not found
      mysql_config --version
      mariadb_config --version
      mysql_config --libs
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

The package is broken I guess but I need to run this now to make it work with my Django project. Any suggestions on any alternates or other command I could run to get the same result?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%2Fbin%2Fsh%3A+1%3A+mysql_config%3A+not+found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Windows

As mysqlclient document mentions Building mysqlclient on Windows is very hard. But there are some binary wheels you can install easily.

> download the [MariaDB C Connector](https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/) and install it. It must be installed in the default location (usually "C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C" or "C:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C" for 32-bit). If you build the connector yourself or install it in a different location, set the environment variable MYSQLCLIENT_CONNECTOR before installing.

#### Linux

You may need to install the Python 3 and MySQL development headers and libraries like so

```bash
# Debian / Ubuntu
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

or

```bash
# Red Hat / CentOS
sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel
```

you can find more details on the package [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)